# AngularJS: Need language information in angularjs from language code

Tags: angularjs, localization, internationalization, locale, angular-translate

In android, I am able to retrieve the language information from the language code itself using Locale class as shown below.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("fr");
locale.getDisplayName(locale); // Français
locale.getDisplayName(Locale.ENGLISH)); // French
```

I need the above information to be retrieved in angularjs from the language code alone. Is it possible to retrieve in HTML directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late on this one, though there is a native API for this, [`window.Navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language).

For example:

```
console.log(window.Navigator.language);  // 'en-US'
```